# Statement about mininum spanning tree

Tags: proof

How do I disprove the following statement: 
If an edge-weighted graph has a unique MST then its edge weights are distinct.

Is it too simple to make a graph that connects 3 vertices in a straight line and have the two edges to be distinct or is that not allowed because to have a unique tree you have to have more than one possible tree?
Also what does "its edge weights are distinct" actually mean, does it mean that no two edges are alike or that not all edges are alike?